# Django messages: How do I remove floating message header on top of the page?

Tags: django, message

Using django messages automatically creates a header on the top of my page.

**views.py**
    messages.error(request, 'Requested break is overlapping')

Does anyone know how to remove the message header? I have figured out how to place messages around my site but I can't get rid of the one on the top of my page, which is messing with my already existent nav bar header.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly... this depends entirely on how you print the messages in your template.

If your code looks like

```
<div id="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}...{% endfor %}
</div>
```

the div, however much space it might take up, will naturally be always printed, regardless if there are messages or not.

You can wrap the `<div>` in `{% if messages %}...{% endif %}` to avoid this.